# Fast way to get specific data from HTML string using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I avoided a lot to come here share my problem. I have googled a lot and find some solutions but not confirmed. 
First I explain My Problem.

I have a CKEditor in my site to let the users post comments. Suppose a user clicks two posts to Multi quote them, the data will be like this in CKEditor

```
<div class="quote" user_name="david_sa" post_id="223423">
This is Quoted Text 
</div>

<div class="quote" user_name="richard12" post_id="254555">
This is Quoted Text 
</div>

<div class="original">
This is the Comment Text 
</div>
```

I want to get all the elements separately in php as below

```
user_name = david_sa
post_id = 223423;
quote_text = This is Quoted Text

user_name = david_sa
post_id = richard12;
quote_text = This is Quoted Text

original_comment = This is the Comment Text
```

I want to get the data in above format in PHP. I have googled and found the preg_match_all() PHP function near to my problem, that uses the REGEX to match the string patterns. But I am not confirmed that is it a legitimate and efficient solution or there is some better solution. If You have any better solution Please Suggest Me.

Comment: weird, two questions in a row asking about how to parse html with regexp. The correct way is using simplexml or DOM to parse (x)html and get attrs and nodes values

Comment: @Alexey - i am currently reading "PHP Object-Oriented Solutions" to strong my oop and going to read chapter on simpleXML, but i think why i should read it and going to skip it and suddenly i come here. now i understand the value of simpleXML  and reading that chap. thanks. sorry for unrelated comment.

Comment: n/p - see someone gave you working code below using DOM extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for this. It takes very few lines of code to parse HTML and extract just about anything from it.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(
'<html><body>' . '

<div class="quote" user_name="david_sa" post_id="223423">
This is Quoted Text 
</div>

<div class="quote" user_name="richard12" post_id="254555">
This is Quoted Text 
</div>

<div class="original">
This is the Comment Text 
</div>

' . '</body></html>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$quote = $xpath->query("//div[@class='quote']");
echo $quote->length; // 2
echo $quote->item(0)->getAttribute('user_name'); // david_sa
echo $quote->item(1)->getAttribute('post_id');   // 254555

// foreach($quote as $div) works as expected

$original = $xpath->query("//div[@class='original']");
echo $original->length;             // 1
echo $original->item(0)->nodeValue; // This is the Comment Text
```

If you are not familiar with [XPath syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx) then [here are a few examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) to get you started.

Comment: +1 Anyone can provide a link. Your advice, example, and links to more examples/expalantion make this a superb answer.

Comment: @Salman A Thanks For Providing Code Example, You have saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using regex's to process HTML/XML. This is what [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) are built for.

You problem seems relatively simple, so you should be able to get away with using SimpleXML (aptly named, huh?)

Answer (score 0):

Do not even try regex to parse html. I would recommend simple html dom. Get it here: [php html parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)